# Does the payment due to the ads placed on our site gets low to some extent due to adblock extensions?

Tags: payments, advertising, google-chrome

I am new to ads and payments, Today I realized that even I use the adblock extension on Google Chrome, so now if the visitor of my site also use this extension, then is my earning affected by that extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to answer this question but here is your answer:

- If the they disable adverts they can't click your adverts therefor this would reduce your earnings - but with this said people who are likely to disable adverts are less likely to click adverts in anycase but sometimes they can get drawn in if the advert is appealing to them.